# MacBook Pro Mid 2012 crashing after SSD upgrade

Tags: macos, ssd, crash

I recently upgrade my MBP from mid 2012. I added an SSD from Plextor M6S 256GB. There's a recurring problem that the MBP crashes after long periods of hibernation, and the following error is given.

```
Anonymous UUID:       5C280B76-FC9D-61DE-F8E2-1AAFB953D1B1

Thu Mar 26 08:56:33 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff802a89e3e4): "Hibernate restore error e00002bf"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.10.73/iokit/Kernel/IOHibernateIO.cpp:3330
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff816235bb30 : 0xffffff802a32fe41 
0xffffff816235bbb0 : 0xffffff802a89e3e4 
0xffffff816235bc90 : 0xffffff802a425835 
0xffffff816235bce0 : 0xffffff7fad015e09 
0xffffff816235bd20 : 0xffffff7fad01965b 
0xffffff816235bd40 : 0xffffff802a8f188b 
0xffffff816235bd90 : 0xffffff802a91a6fc 
0xffffff816235bdf0 : 0xffffff802a8c51a7 
0xffffff816235be60 : 0xffffff802a8bbdba 
0xffffff816235bef0 : 0xffffff802a8ca5c8 
0xffffff816235bf40 : 0xffffff802a8d34ad 
0xffffff816235bf80 : 0xffffff802a8d36a8 
0xffffff816235bfb0 : 0xffffff802a414dd7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(3.1)[D4068745-B4F6-3559-BB69-A15F0B4F92B4]@0xffffff7fad00b000->0xffffff7fad069fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7faaf0c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7faab24000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: kext-dev-mode=1

Mac OS version:
14C1514

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Thu Feb 26 19:26:47 PST 2015; root:xnu-2782.10.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 270413F7-3B44-3602-894F-AC0D392FCF8E
Kernel slide:     0x000000002a000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802a200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802a100000
System model name: MacBookPro9,1 (Mac-4B7AC7E43945597E)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11651702730029
last loaded kext at 5513540144809: com.huawei.driver.HuaweiDataCardDriver   5.01.01 (addr 0xffffff7fad0ee000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 5580680251667: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.2.2b5 (addr 0xffffff7fad0b3000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.MBB.driver.MBBEthernetData  5.01.01
com.MBB.driver.MBBACMData   5.01.01
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    1.1.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.15.5
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   269.25
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   269.25
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.2
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.3
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   910.26.12
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 269.25
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.2
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.6.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.8.6
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.1d38
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.10.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   710.55
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 710.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro9,1, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B09, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.1f175
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D3136303043392D384752534C000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.159.13.12)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Serial ATA Device: PLEXTOR PX-256M6S, 256.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading this article on MacWorld.  It has to do with TRIM technology, OS X, and MBP.  Your drive may not be *fully* compatible.

[Mac Won't Boot - About Yosemite and 3rd Party SSD](http://www.macworld.com/article/2849366/mac-wont-boot-about-yosemite-and-your-third-party-ssd.html)

To verify that your newly installed HDD works you can do two things:

1)  Download, burn, and boot [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com).  There are a number of HDD utilities you can run that will test out your drive for you.  Since you are no longer booting OS X when you boot this CD, you are bypassing any software issues you may be experiencing from Apple and OS X.

There is a [USB Flash Boot Drive](http://wiki.ultimatebootcd.com/?title=Tutorials:USB_Installation) option instead of a CD (I personally use this).

This will tell you if your drive is good and it is communicating with your hardware.  If it fails at any point, then it is a safe bet that you have a hardware issue.  If everything passes, it's on to step 2.

2) Install a pervious version of OS X; Mavericks or Mountain Lion will do.  If your computer boots, then the problem lies with Yosemite and the compatibility with the new drive.

***Do a Time Machine Backup First***  This way you can restore all your files after this procedure.

Do a fresh install of ML or Mavericks.  Let it wipe and partition the drive.  If everything boots properly, you have narrowed down the problem to Yosemite.    Which means

a)  Yosemite isn't compatible with your drive
b)  Your TRIM utility doesn't work.

At that point, you have two options:  downgrade to ML or Mavericks or get a new drive with TRIM and buy a USB enclosure and make this drive an external USB HDD.

Comment: I forgot to add, I have enabled TRIM using Trim Enabler from Cindori. Is that causing problems?

Comment: I am not familiar with that 3rd party utility.  However, from experience, utilities like this one designed to get around a flaw (even intentional ones) can be flaky.  Is it possible to test out with a known compatible drive?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No that is not possible. I can see the error is occurring due to apple's IOKit.

Comment: Your other option would be to download and install a previous version of OS X like Mavericks or Mountain Lion.  I'll update the answer

Comment: Alright I will try that once I get home.